# <html> and <body> Tags 100% Height Fail

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, document-body

I have an application which requires me to use CSS to set the height of the `<html>` and `<body>` tags to 100%, like this ([JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/QQvdw/1/)):

```
html, body {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #141414;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I've included all of the CSS that styles these tags. However, I **always** have a scrollbar which allows me to scroll down about 20px, regardless of how large or small the content of the page really is. This is problem also persists on screes of any size.

I can see why in these screenshots. Note that the body has an ID of `#container`, but this is simply used for JS targeting, not CSS styling:

[image]

A 3D perspective of the same page, showing the `<body>` tag is slid down from the top of the `<html>` tag:

[image]

Since I don't have any margin or padding on any of these tags, and since none of the HTML elements near the top of the page have any margin or padding to push the `<body>` tag downward, I'm really stuck.

How can I fix the CSS such that the `<body>` tag is flush with the top of the page?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: +1  for 3d . ( can be made in FF)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Haha... thanks. FF is where I did it. :D

Comment: what style is on the container?

Comment: your container probably has a `margin-top: 20px` ?

Comment: Good points. `#container` is simply used as a target for JS. No styles are applied via CSS to `#container`. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Can you post a little more html/css on jsfiddle?

Comment: OK, then the first visible element on your page has a `margin-top: 20px ?` :)

Comment: @smang Posted the JSFiddle version http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/QQvdw/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
header {
    margin: 0px 17% 0px 17%;
}
```

Comment: or header {
    padding: 20px 17% 0px 17%;
}

Comment: I had to soak that in for a second........... I couldn't believe I didn't think of that. Yes, bingo that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing). You can "fix" this by adding `padding: 0.01px` to your body.

Hopefully my second attempt at answering this question isn't as stupid as my first XD

Answer (score -4):

Seems like you have a new line or a space between `<html>` and `<body>`...

Try this:

```
<html><body>
    ...
</body></html>
```

instead of:

```
<html>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whitespace won't have any effect there.

Comment: If you write whole code in single line (minified) it will also work. New line does not help in this case.